# Ionic 2: Using Cordova Plugins

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I did a lot of googling and couldn't seem to come up with much of an answer, how does the syntax of calling Cordova plugins in Ionic 2 work.

Like for example, in Ionic 1:
I was using a facebook plugin, and I would call it like:         $cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email","name","last_name","first_name","birthday","age_range","link"]).then(function (success) {

I would also 'inject' it and add it as a dependency. Both things I am not sure how to do with Ionic 2.

I read somewhere that with Ionic 2 that isn't as nesscary, but I am still unsure

Answer (score 10):

Steps to use cordova plugin:

1. Add plugin

   cordova plugin add [name of plugin]

Actually this is the only step to use cordova plugin. But there could be an error message when you're using Typescript. For example:

> ERROR in [default] /Users/myname/Projects/ionic2/demo/app/pages/home/home.ts:21:12 
>   Property 'device' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

2. To fix the error message for Typescript. You can simple add this line to your .ts file, for example:

   declare var navigator : any;

Comment: Thank you so much..... your line 

`declare var navigator : any;`

saved me. I was trying to add cordova media plugin and the above error irritated me... with your tip, it worked like magic.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something similar to ngCordova. Then there is also similar project for Ionic 2 called as ionic-native. Check this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

So for example, you want to use Camera in a Ionic Page. You would have to first import the plugin, something like this:

```
import {Camera} from 'ionic-native';
```

and After that, inside the Page class you can do the thing like this:

```
Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   let base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }, (err) => {
});
```

Also remember that you have to first install plugin via

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

I hope it will answer you question.

Comment: That is a nice suggestion, but still not all cordova plugins are reflected in native package. For instance ``SocialVk`` - I used answer from @Zhou Hao

Comment: I just answered it according to the question

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2 still has a lot of issues that have to be worked out for full app development in Typescript.  There are several cordova plugins that are not "ionic-native" plugins for instance the cordova Paypal plugin which you could import and inject into your angular 1 / ionic 1 application without a problem, but will not be available to you via the "navigator" or just the class name in an Ionic 2 Typescript app.

Hopefully this will be addressed soon so that you can import these "other plugins" into your app just like a regular module so that it will be available in your typescript code editor, i.e. VS Code so you can visually debug.