# How to use Cordova plugins in an Angular 2 mobile applications

Tags: cordova, typescript, angular, cordova-plugins

I want to include a Cordova plugin in my Angular2 app. Been googling whole day, no big win yet.

Can anyone suggest? How can this be done?
After including, how can I call the Cordova methods?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372663/ionic-2-using-cordova-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the plugin by using cordova commands

like cordova plugin add "PLUGINNAME"

Comment: Which folder are you doing this? `Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`