# cannot use cordova plugin to open files under ionic 2 and typescript

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am developing an android app based on **ionic 2** using **typescript**.
I would like o open a PDF file inside my app with another app that is registered for the fyletype (e.g. Acrobat Reader).
Therefore i tried the two standard plugins:

https://github.com/disusered/cordova-open
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Although ive added both plugins via "ionic plugin add ..." and of course played around with several combination referencing to it 
the result is always that they ere not found

**cordova-open**

```
var open = cordova.plugins.disusered.open;
```

Property 'disusered' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.

**cordova-plugin-file-opener2**

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    filePath, 
    fileMIMEType, 
    {
        error : function(){ }, 
        success : function(){ } 
    } 
);
```

Property 'fileOpener2' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.

I am running the app on an emulator via **ionic run android**

Could you please give some hint how i can achieve to use one of these plugins?
Thank you very much

Shane

Comment: What about running on a physical device? I ran it on my phone and it is working fine.

Comment: I do have the same effect running the app on a real device. do i need to install some special typescript files from cordova, ngcordova or phonegap? do i need to add any special import  in the header e.g. `import { _PLUGINNAME_} from 'ionic-native';`

Comment: Take a look at your project file structure. There should be a folder called node_modules and plugins. Inside node_modules contains `ionic-native` which is a set of wrappers for Cordova/phonegap plugins. (E.g. if you use a plugin from ionic-native like GeoLocation, then you would need to include the import header) Check out the Ionic framework docs for more info.

But if you use `ionic plugin add ...`, it would create a folder within plugins folder. So you should not be required to add any special import header.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372663/ionic-2-using-cordova-plugins